# SRUM (system resource usage monitor) forensics - Windows server?

Tags: forensics, windows-10, windows-server

Having read a couple of articles on the SRUM DB and its use in forensics, I started digging around in Server 2016. The path referenced in the articles is not found in Sever 2016 `%systemroot%\System32\sru`. I suspect that the feature is disabled as servers might generate too much data to keep the DB a sensible size, or it may have a performance impact. Has anyone found a method of enabling this feature in server 2016?
[SRUM forensics overview](https://www.sans.org/cyber-security-summit/archives/file/summit-archive-1492184583.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The file you're looking for, `%systemroot%\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat`, is managed by the `Diagnostic Policy Service`. If the file isn't present, you may find that service isn't running.

Take a look in `services.msc` and check to see if the service is running. `Diagnostic Policy Service` should be able to create the missing file when run.

Comment: Thanks, Diagnostic Policy Service is running - though the related diagnostic policy host is not (this supports local system context). I wonder if there is some related configuration that needs to changed for the SRUM DB to be created?